# Cant get ember model observer to fire on property change

Tags: ember.js

I have a model with a property 'state' which I want to observe

```
App.Batch = DS.Model.extend({
  state: DS.attr('string'),

  stateChanged: function () {
   console.log('observed')
  }.observes('state')
});
```

The batch model is updated via a call to batch.reload()

```
  _.each(pertinentBatches, function (batch) {
    batch.reload();
  });
```

I can verify in the ember console that the state property is changing once the batch is reloaded. Why wouldn't this cause the observer to fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the model is reinitialized when reload is called, observers do not fire on init by default, try adding `.on('init')` to your observer.

Comment: @Holger I believe I did answer the question? I have clarified the answer a little

Comment: Basically it read like a guess, now with the clarification it looks better.

Comment: `init` would be called only when the record is originally created, not when it was reloaded to the best of my knowledge. As far as I can see, the observer should fire in this situation, so the problem is likely to lie elsewhere.

Comment: This essentially covered the issue. I ended up moving the logic out of any observer altogether but the issue did stem from the fact that  reload was not causing the observer to fire ostensibly due to it reinitializing the object.